# Can I pipe into describe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, hmisc

Describe from Hmisc is one of my favorite functions. It gives a great looking summary for a dataset.

I'd like to be able to filter a dataset with dplyr and then pass a single column to describe().

Something like this

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 5) %>% describe(cyl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `select` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 5) %>% select(cyl) %>% describe()

1  Variables      21  Observations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cyl 
       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd 
      21        0        2    0.668    7.333   0.9333 
                      
Value          6     8
Frequency      7    14
Proportion 0.333 0.667
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few other ways of doing this.

Wrapping the `rhs` in braces prevents the `lhs` from being used as the first argument.

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 5) %>% { describe(.$cyl) }
```

`magrittr` also has the exposition pipe operator, `%$%` which does not pass on the first argument.

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 5) %$% describe(cyl)
```

`with` can also be used.

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 5) %>% with(describe(cyl))
```